# Keeping XDMCP session alive through sleep/hibernate

Tags: linux, windows, hibernate

I've got the Xming X server running on Windows. I "view" my Linux desktop on it remotely using XDMCP.

It all works well, but if I put my Windows box to sleep or hibernate and come back a few hours later, I've lost my X session (Xming window blank) and I have to close the window and create a new XDMCP session.

Is there any way to keep XDMCP session going when the OS hosting the X server sleeps/hibernates?

I don't know what's relevant here, but I'm running GDM & KDE on Debian Unstable, Xming on WinXP.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head, I'd say no. You're losing the TCP connection so X shuts down the session as if you'd been knocked off the network. If you want a persistent connection, look into VNC or NX (FreeNX or NoMachine). I'm too new to post links, but you can use Google on either option and you'll get usable results.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Matt. I'd never heard of NX/NoMachine, so it's good to learn about it.

My Linux instance runs as a domU VM on Xen so I'll have to see if I can get it to use a hidden frame buffer that I can VNC into, as the dom0 screen is already being used by someone else.